# IIRF v2.0 - Help with Domain's and Redirects

Tags: regex, dns, subdomain, iirf

I have a primary domain - let's call it **xyz.com**. I also have several other secondary domains such as **abc.com def.com, ghi.com**, etc.. These domain all have the same content.

I am trying to do a URL redirect in IIRF that will take any of the secondary domains, and replace it with my primary xyz domain.

This is the closest I have gotten.

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(?!(.*)\.xyz\.com)$
RedirectRule ^/(.*)$        http://*1.xyz.com/$1
```

Problem #1: with this if I navigate to **123.abc.com**, I am brought to **.xyz.com** (I am losing my sub-domain, I thought I could retrieve that with '*1').

Problem #2: even when I go to **www.xyz.com**, I am redirected to **.xyz.com** this rule should obviously ignore any **xyz.com** domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me a week, but I got it.

```
##### handles 3-part domains like "xxx.yyy.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(?!xyz).*\.com$        
    RedirectRule ^/(.*)$ http://*1.xyz.com/$1 [R=301]
```

and

```
##### handles 2-part domains like "yyy.com"      
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!xyz).*\.com$        
    RedirectRule ^/(.*)$ http://xyz.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
#not in main.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.*main.com [NC]
#get the subdomain as a backreference to use in the RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+$ [NC]
#Rewrite the new URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1main.com/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I'm not the most uber regex guru though, so there may be some border cases which provide unexpected results

Comment: Im really going for a Redirect here. Can I just substitute RedirectRule for RewriteRule?

Comment: ohh, my bad, I saw RedirectRule as RewriteRule. In any case, add `R` to the flags at the end of the RewriteRule to use a redirect instead. You can even specify an HTTP redirect code eg. R=301

Comment: The regEx is not quite right. I got "?!" means "not". Right now I am not getting any effect with your code in place...

Comment: http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf20Help/html/e013a406-9f3a-4385-b986-6c4c410dad48.htm

Comment: Up-voted for your effort. Was able to get a direct answer from the developer. http://iirf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=226802